# C# how to append errors into 1 single messagebox?

Tags: c#, python

This is my current code in C#:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("User Field Is Empty");
    return;
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Document Reference Code Field Is Empty");
    return;
}
```

What is the correct way to create an array and append to the array to show 1 MessageBox and bullet point the values that are empty, instead of having multiple MessageBoxes and clicking 'OK' for each error message?

I am trying to replicate it same as this Python code:

```
errors = []
if self.nameEntry.get() == '':
     errors.append('User')
if self.documentReferenceCodeEntry.get() == '':
    errors.append('Document Reference')
        if errors:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Following fields are empty:" +'\n' + '\n'.join(errors))
            return('error')
```

What the above code is, if the field is empty, append it to `errors` array and at the end, show all errors into 1 messagebox.

This is the output of Python code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a List to store the errors and then display the MessageBox if the list is not empty

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    errors.Add("User");
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    errors.Add("Document Reference Code");
}

if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    errors.Insert(0, "The following fields are empty:");
    string message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: What does the `<string>` does?

Comment: See [`List<T> class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It is an implementation of a more vast concept called [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: Also, if there are errors, how do I stop continuing running code? I know I can add `return` at end.. but is that correct way of doing it?

Comment: It depends from the logic of the code. if there is no reason to continue you add a return inside the if block.

Comment: I have placed it in the `if(errors.Count >0)`. It works like a dream now :)